# Babel plugin-proposal-decorators not working as expected

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, babeljs

I have added these two devDependencies in my `package.json`:

```
"@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "^7.1.0",
"@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators": "^7.1.6",
```

In `.babelrc` a file I have added them as plugins:

```
{
    "presets": ["module:metro-react-native-babel-preset"],
    "plugins": [
        ["@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators", { "legacy": true}],
        ["@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties", { "loose": true}]
    ]
}
```

I am using mobx so observable is the clean syntax, my file looks like this:

```
class AppStore {
  @observable username = ''
}

export default (new AppStore())
```

But it is always showing this error:

[image]

I think I have done it correctly but there is no way to detect whether babel plugins are loaded or not.

Comment: In babel sandbox https://babeljs.io/repl both plugins can't be loaded as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, make sure that you are on the latest version of `metro-react-native-babel-preset`, they released a new minor `0.50.0` only 9 days ago.

If that didn't help, it's likely the problem comes from the fact that the `metro-react-native-babel-preset` [already includes](https://github.com/facebook/metro/blob/master/packages/metro-react-native-babel-preset/src/configs/main.js#L27) the class property plugin, and as you know the order of the plugins [matter](https://github.com/loganfsmyth/babel-plugin-transform-decorators-legacy#note-order-of-plugins-matters), **you need to have the decorator run before the class property plugin**.

There has been a lot of discussion on this subject of ordering in babel, and although plugins are supposed to run before presets, it still [would be a problem](https://github.com/babel/babel/issues/4882#issuecomment-286615366). Unfortunately PR [#5735](https://github.com/babel/babel/pull/5735) to add plugin ordering capabilities is still a work in progress.

What you could do in the meantime could be to either fork your own `metro-react-native-babel-preset` and add the decorator plugin before the class property plugin at the place I pointed. You might also try to make your own babel preset including the two plugins in the right order and add it after the metro one, as presets are loaded in reverse order, last to first as seen [here](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/presets#preset-ordering).

Also worth a try would be to start the packager using `yarn start --reset-cache` which might solve issues caused by a bad/outdated cache.

Comment: "..and as you know the order of the plugins matter, you need to have the decorator run before the class property plugin" - THANK YOU! I've been banging my head against a wall for the last few hours trying to get decorators to work in my workspace and this was the issue 

Comment: @Aperçu hello thanks for info. The way I solved was running `yarn start` instead of default metro bundler that appears when i type `react-native run-ios` I think it is better you can add that as answer so I can mark your answer as a solution?

Comment: Because `run-ios` spawns the same `start` command, it's likely your issue was due to a bad cache rather than simply using yarn